# Using Some Labels Contained in a Text File to Split the file into separate files

Tags: python

I have a text file that has been created by combining content of separate files. I now want to reverse the situation. Let me give some examples:

```
ID:t-599108
===================
===================
===================
ID:t-599108
===================
===================
===================
ID:t-594356
===================
===================
===================
ID:t-594356
===================
===================
===================
ID:t-594356
===================
===================
```

The ========= are texts after the ID. I want to separate the file into different files using the ID. Please, the ID's are repeated within the files. The resulting files are to be named using the ID's.  Can I achieve this using Python or any other language? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sure:

```
lines = """your massive body of text""".splitlines()
text = ""
id = ""
for line in lines:
  if "ID:" in line:
    if id != "": # previously existed, then save to file
      id = line[3:]
      open(id + ".txt").write(text) # write to a file like "t-111.txt"  
    id = line[3:] # take id
    text = "" # reset text
  else:
    text += line
```

Comment: The program is not generating the expected result yet. The files were created rightly but only one ID's text was put in each file. The text of repeated ID's as well as ID's header i.e. ID:t-599108 and its text for all occurrence of the ID were expected to be in the file created and this is expected for all files to be created